# Using spring cloud namespace and two DataSources

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-connectors

I have a Spring Integration WAR component that I'm updating to run in private PCF. I have two DataSources and a RabbitMQ connection factory defined in the application.

I see an article from Thomas Risberg on using the cloud namespace and handling multiple services of the same time - https://spring.io/blog/2011/11/09/using-cloud-foundry-services-with-spring-part-3-the-cloud-namespace. This is handled by using @Autowired and @Qualifier annotations.

I'm wondering how this can be achieved though when we're not @Autowired and @Qualifier annotations, e.g. wiring a DataSource into a JdbcTemplate. Here we do not have the ability to specify a @Qualifier annotation.

My application is Spring XML config based. I do have ability to use @Autowired and @Qualifier annotations on one of the DataSources, but the other is JPA entity manager. See code snippet.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="activity-monitor" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.format_sql=true
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <beans profile="cloud">
        <cloud:data-source id="dataSource" service-name="actmon-db-service" />
    </beans>
```

Java Build Pack: java_buildpack_offline java-buildpack-offline-v2.4.zip
Spring Auto-reconfiguration version 1.4.0.

**UPDATE:** This is the full config for both data sources, including PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with properties loaded from data source using DAO.

```
<bean id="cic.application.ppc" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
    <property name="properties" ref="cic.application.properties"/> 
    <property name="locations" ref="cic.application.propertyLocations"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="cic.application.properties" class="java.util.Properties">
    <constructor-arg value="#{cicPropertiesService.properties}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="cic.properties.propertiesService" name="cicPropertiesService"
    class="com.emc.it.eis.properties.service.DefaultPropertiesService">
    <constructor-arg index="0"
        ref="cic.properties.propertiesDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="cic.properties.propertiesDao" class="com.emc.it.eis.properties.dao.JdbcPropertiesDao">
    <constructor-arg ref="cic.properties.dataSource" />
</bean>

<beans profile="default">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="cic.properties.dataSource"
        jndi-name="jdbc/intdb" />
</beans>

<beans profile="cloud">
    <cloud:data-source id="cic.properties.dataSource" service-name="oracle-cicadm-db-service" />
</beans>

<beans>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="actmonDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="activity-monitor" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.format_sql=true
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="default">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
        jndi-name="jdbc/actmon" />
</beans>

<beans profile="cloud">
    <cloud:data-source id="actmonDataSource" service-name="postgres-actmon-db-service" />
</beans>

<beans profile="default,cloud">
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Output from CF when I deploy https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3986a1a7cea4f20c096e. Note it is skipping auto re-configuration of javax.sql.DataSources

Comment: Auto-reconfiguration of bound services in Spring applications is only enabled when you have one service of a given type bound to your app. See http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/spring-service-bindings.html#auto. In this case, you are doing manual configuration of the datasources, so auto-reconfig is not needed. If you have multiple databases bound, auto-reconfig has no way of knowing which bound db should be used for which purpose.

Comment: Are you sure the "cloud" profile is getting activated when your app is pushed? Some versions of the Java buildpack didn't automatically activate this profile in all cases. Try running `cf set-env appname SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE cloud` to make sure.

Comment: Thanks. The docs make it a bit clearer. I had thought that auto-reconfiguration and spring-cloud-connectors were tied together. Manual configuration implies spring-cloud. So for multiple data sources the recommendation in the docs says to use a the @Qualifier annotation to distinguish. The log do indicate that the cloud profile is being activated.

Comment: Think I've identified the issue here Scott. We are using a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and loading the properties into it via a DAO configured to point at the `cloud:data-source` `cic.properties.dataSource`. `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is a `PriorityOrdered` implementing bean factory post processor. The problem here it seems is that the `CloudServiceIntroducer` class that creates the service beans is just a regular bean factory post processor and hence is not present when loading the property sources. Is there a way around this issue, maybe implement `PriorityOrdered` tks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the post from Thomas is pretty old, and references a deprecated support library. Instead of the `org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-runtime:0.8.1` dependency, you should use [Spring Cloud Connectors dependencies](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors#including-cloud-connectors) instead.

You can then follow the [instructions provided](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/tree/master/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector#creating-service-beans-1) for using XML configuration with Spring Cloud Connectors. With multiple services of the same type, you will need to specify the name of the service for each bean. Following your example, and assuming you created two CF database services named `inventory-db` and `customer-db`, that might look something like this:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="inventory-dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="activity-monitor" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.format_sql=true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<beans profile="cloud">
    <cloud:data-source id="inventory-dataSource" service-name="inventory-db">
    <cloud:data-source id="customer-dataSource" service-name="customer-db">
</beans>
```

Comment: Hi Scott. Edited my question with additional info. Sorry the reference to that post was something I found. I'm actually not using those libraries. I'm using latest GA releases of spring cloud connectors.

Comment: No problem, I wasn't sure if you were using the older libs or not, just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve the issue by using the factory bean used by the spring cloud:data-source, `CloudDataSourceFactory`. Creating an instance of this and wiring up the config including the `service-name` of the CF service. This avoids the issue of our PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer trying to use the data source before our the bean has even been defined.

```
    <!--
        configure cloud data source for using CloudDataSourceFactory; this is what spring cloud:data-source is using;
        required to manually wire this data source bean as cloud:data-source bean gets defined in a phase after our
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean.
    -->
    <bean id="cic.properties.dataSource" class="org.springframework.cloud.service.relational.CloudDataSourceFactory">
        <constructor-arg value="oracle-cicadm-db-service" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <!-- configuring minimal data source as it is used only to bootstrap properties on app start-up -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.cloud.service.relational.DataSourceConfig">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.cloud.service.PooledServiceConnectorConfig.PoolConfig">
                        <constructor-arg value="0" />
                        <constructor-arg value="2" />
                        <constructor-arg value="180" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <!-- ConnectionConfig not required for cic.properties.dataSource so setting to null -->
                <constructor-arg value="#{ null }" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```